cohomological spectral sequence of a CW-complex
I'm studying Lecture 21.1 of Fomenko-Fuchs.
Let $X$ a CW-complex with skeletons $\{X^{p}\}_{p\in\mathbb{N}}$. We consider $C=C^*(X ; G)=\bigoplus_r C^r(X ; G)$ with the differential $\delta: C^r(X ; G) \rightarrow C^{r+1}(X ; G)$ and the (decreasing) filtration $F^p C=C^*\left(X, X_{p-1} ; G\right) \subset C^*(X ; G)$. This yields a spectral sequence $\left\{E_r^{p q}, d_r^{p q}: E_r^{p q} \rightarrow E_r^{p+r, q-r+1}\right\}$ with
$$
\begin{aligned}
& E_r^{p q}=\frac{C^{p+q}\left(X, X_{p-1} ; G\right) \cap \delta^{-1}\left(C^{p+q+1}\left(X, X_{p+r-1} ; G\right)\right)}{\left[C^{p+q}\left(X, X_p ; G\right) \cap \delta^{-1}\left(C^{p+q+1}\left(X, X_{p+r-1} ; G\right)\right)\right]+\left[C^{p+q}\left(X, X_{p-1} ; G\right) \cap \delta\left(C^{p+q-1}\left(X, X_{p-r} ; G\right)\right)\right]}. \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$
They immidetialy say that $$E_0^{p q}=C^{p+q}\left(X_p, X_{p-1} ; G\right)$$
but if I put $r=0$ this is what i get:
$$E_0^{p q}=\frac{C^{p+q}\left(X, X_{p-1} ; G\right) \cap \delta^{-1}\left(C^{p+q+1}\left(X, X_{p-1} ; G\right)\right)}{\left[C^{p+q}\left(X, X_p ; G\right) \cap \delta^{-1}\left(C^{p+q+1}\left(X, X_{p-1} ; G\right)\right)\right]+\left[C^{p+q}\left(X, X_{p-1} ; G\right) \cap \delta\left(C^{p+q-1}\left(X, X_{p} ; G\right)\right)\right]}=\frac{C^{p+q}\left(X, X_{p-1} ; G\right) }{\left[C^{p+q}\left(X, X_p ; G\right) \right]+\left[ \delta\left(C^{p+q-1}\left(X, X_{p} ; G\right)\right)\right]}=\frac{C^{p+q}\left(X, X_{p-1} ; G\right) }{C^{p+q}\left(X, X_p ; G\right) }.$$
So the question is, why are the two expression equal?
On one hand we have $$\frac{C^{p+q}\left(X, X_{p-1} ; G\right) }{C^{p+q}\left(X, X_p ; G\right)}=\frac{Hom(C_{p+q}(X, X_{p-1}) ; G) }{Hom(C_{p+q}\left(X, X_p) ; G\right) }$$
and on the other hand we have $$C^{p+q}\left(X_p, X_{p-1} ; G\right)=Hom(C_{p+q}\left(X_p, X_{p-1}) ; G\right)$$
but i can't see why they are equal.

Consider the diagram 
with exact rows and vertical maps induced from the "inclusion" $(X, X_{p - 1}) \hookrightarrow (X, X_p)$, $n$ arbitrary.
All groups here are free, so applying $\operatorname{Hom}({{-}}, G)$ gives a diagram 
with exact rows, whence the sequence drawn in gray exists and is exact by the snake lemma, yielding the isomorphism you're looking for.
